# mongodb query by sub-field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to query all `{"module" : "B"}` ?

The following query doesn't work:

```
db.XXX.find({ "_id" : { "module" : "B" } });
```

Thanks a ton!

There data looks like:

```
{
  "_id" : {"module" : "A","date" : ISODate("2013-03-18T07:00:00Z")},
  "value" : {"count" : 1.0}
}

{
  "_id" : {"module" : "B","date" : ISODate("2013-03-18T08:00:00Z")},
  "value" : {"count" : 2.0}
}
```

Comment: This is very wierd, document identifier (_id) field

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try:

```
db.XXX.find({ "_id.module" :  "B" });
```

The difference is your original query would be trying to match on that entire subdocument (i.e. where _id is a subdocument containing a "module" field with value "B" and nothing else)

Reference: [MongoDB Dot Notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

Answer (score 2):

Use dot notation:

```
db.XXX.find({ "_id.module" : "B" })
```

Answer (score 2):

For Exact match on Subdocument

```
    db.bios.find(
   {
     '_id.module': 'B'
   }
)
```

the query uses `dot` notation to access fields in a `subdocument`:

[Refference link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/)

Comment: You've got an extra quote in there after the B (or a missing one before it).