# Parse Query by subfield/dot notation

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

> tl;dr
>
> Can ParseCloud/MongoDB filter by `Pointer<class>.filed` ? By
>   `Pointer<class>.Pointer<class>` ? By existence of data in that filed?

Long question:

`Round` is object which will be played automatically when time will come.

`Payment` object which indicates that user made payment. When payment being spent we set field `round` to it.

`Player` which links online `User` with `Payment`

I need to query player for few conditions:

1. `Player`

   - online
   - has valid(no `round` and `valid` equal to 'valid') `payment`
2. `Player`

   - `user` equal to specific user
   - has no `payment`
3. `Player`

   - `user` equal to specific user
   - has valid(no `round` and `valid` equal to 'valid') payment

And I made everything to work except validating `Payment` **inside** `Player` query.

Here is condition **1** from the list.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(keys.Player);  
query.skip(0);
query.limit(oneRoundMaxPlayers);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo(keys.last_online_date, lastAllowedOnline);

// looks like no filter applied here
query.doesNotExist("payment.round"); 

query.exists(keys.payment);

// This line will make query return 0 elements 
// query.equalTo("payment.valid", "valid"); 

query.include(keys.user);
query.include(keys.payment);
```

Here is **2 OR 3**

```
var queryPaymentExists = new Parse.Query(keys.Player);  
queryPaymentExists.skip(0);
queryPaymentExists.limit(1);
queryPaymentExists.exists(keys.payment);

//This line not filtering
queryPaymentExists.doesNotExist(keys.payment + "." + keys.round); 

queryPaymentExists.equalTo(keys.user, user);

// This line makes query always return 0 elements
// queryPaymentExists.equalTo(keys.payment + "." + keys.valid, keys.payment_valid);

var queryPaymentDoesNotExist = new Parse.Query(keys.Player);  
queryPaymentDoesNotExist.skip(0);
queryPaymentDoesNotExist.limit(1);
queryPaymentDoesNotExist.doesNotExist(keys.payment);
queryPaymentDoesNotExist.equalTo(keys.user, user);

var compoundQuery = Parse.Query.or(queryPaymentExists, queryPaymentDoesNotExist);
compoundQuery.include(keys.user);
compoundQuery.include(keys.payment);
compoundQuery.include(keys.payment + "." + keys.round);
```

I've checked logs from Mongo and they looks following

```
    verbose: REQUEST for [GET] /classes/Player: {
  "include": "user,payment,payment.round",
  "where": {
    "$or": [
      {
        "payment": {
          "$exists": true
        },
        "payment.round": {
          "$exists": false
        },
        "user": {
          "__type": "Pointer",
          "className": "_User",
          "objectId": "ASPKs6UVwb"
        }
      },
      {
        "payment": {
          "$exists": false
        },
        "user": {
          "__type": "Pointer",
          "className": "_User",
          "objectId": "ASPKs6UVwb"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is response:

```
verbose: RESPONSE from [GET] /classes/Player: {
  "response": {
    "results": [
      {
        "objectId": "VHU9uwmLA7",
        "last_online_date": {
          "__type": "Date",
          "iso": "2017-10-28T15:15:23.547Z"
        },
        "user": {
          "objectId": "ASPKs6UVwb",
          "username": "cn92Ekv5WPJcuHjkmTajmZMDW",

          },
          "createdAt": "2017-10-22T11:43:16.804Z",
          "updatedAt": "2017-10-25T09:23:20.035Z",


          "ACL": {
            "*": {
              "read": true
            },
            "ASPKs6UVwb": {
              "read": true,
              "write": true
            }
          },
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "_User"
        },
        "createdAt": "2017-10-27T21:03:35.442Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-10-28T15:15:23.556Z",
        "payment": {
          "objectId": "nr7ln7U3eJ",
          "payment_date": {
            "__type": "Date",
            "iso": "2017-10-27T23:42:50.614Z"
          },
          "user": {
            "__type": "Pointer",
            "className": "_User",
            "objectId": "ASPKs6UVwb"
          },
          "createdAt": "2017-10-27T23:42:50.624Z",
          "updatedAt": "2017-10-28T15:12:30.131Z",
          "valid": "valid",
          "round": {
            "objectId": "jF9gqG4ndh",
            "round_date": {
              "__type": "Date",
              "iso": "2017-10-28T15:12:00.027Z"
            },
            "createdAt": "2017-10-28T15:11:00.036Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-10-28T15:12:30.108Z",
            ,
            "ACL": {
              "*": {
                "read": true
              }
            },
            "__type": "Object",
            "className": "Round"
          },
          "ACL": {
            "ASPKs6UVwb": {
              "read": true
            }
          },
          "__type": "Object",
          "className": "Payment"
        },
        "ACL": {
          "ASPKs6UVwb": {
            "read": true
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see that response contains payment.round.

My question is following:

1. Can ParseCloud/MongoDB filter by `Pointer<class>.filed` ? By `Pointer<class>.Pointer<class>` ? By existence of data in that filed?
2. How can I workaround in situation when I need to check field presence if `User` can have may `Players`, `User` can have many `Payments`.

**UPD** 
As far as I found mongo should support filtering by "dot notation"
[mongodb query by sub-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632525/mongodb-query-by-sub-field)
So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

1. No
2. Simplify your data structure

**Long answer:**

Dot notation can be used to

- *include* documents of pointers, as you already did in your code, e.g. `include(keys.user)`
- *filter* for properties of fields, e.g. `{properyA: 1, propertyB: 2}`. All the data is in the field, not in another document in another collection that is referenced by a Parse pointer.

Dot notation cannot be used as filter parameter for referenced pointers in a Parse query. MongoDB also does not support such a filtering, the concept of `pointer` is one by Parse and not by MongoDB. In a NoSQL environment like MongoDB there are no relations between tables to be used in the query language, as it is not a "relational database" like an SQL database. However Parse provides some comfort of an SQL for simple queries with its concepts of `pointer`, `compoundQuery` and `matchesKeyInQuery`.

If that is not sufficient in your case, simply add the fields to the collection. To the expense that you may have the same fields and data in multiple collections but with the advantage of faster query execution time.

Finding the right data structure is one of the big topics for NoSQL as there is no general right structure. The collections and document structures are basically designed as a trade off between:

- execution performance
- query necessity / frequency
- security (access level)
- and data storage size

And they are liquid and can change over time. As your app and its queries mutate you'd also change the data structure if the long term gain is greater than the one time effort.